# Gödel's Asymmetry

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

First of all, *The Liar sentence*, off of which Gödel constructed his argument.  L = This sentence is false. As the story goes, *L implies contradiction* AND *~L implies contradiction*. So far so bad.

Then G = *The Gödel sentence* = This sentence is unprovable (the resemblance to L is striking; of course a posteriori, apologies ) *~G implies contradiction* (proof that no proof). *G implies then **incompleteness***.

Now, *proof* is mighty *similar*, if *not identical* to *true*, but the *symmetry* which we see with L (both truth branches are dead ends) is *broken* with G (one branch "appears" *useful*, G is true).

*Quide vide*?

---

*Do nfr things*

Comment: There is an old essay on this, Soto-Andrade and Varela[[84](https://www.academia.edu/9065607/Self_reference_and_fixed_points_A_discussion_and_an_extension_of_Lawveres_Theorem?email_work_card=title)]. The liar paradox is put to use by Tarski in a way that reflects Gödel; so far, on the other hand, "This sentence is unknown," hasn't clearly been used "limitatively," despite some attempts to correlate it with [Fitch's paradox of knowability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fitch-paradox/).

Comment: See Santos[[17](https://repositorio.ul.pt/bitstream/10451/48387/1/Santos%20R%20-%202017%20-%20Fitch%27s%20Paradox%20of%20Knowability%20and%20the%20Knower%20Paradox.pdf)) though for critical discussion of that attempted correlation.

Comment: This striking resemblance yet asymmetry is metaphorically clear, the 'unqualified' L is paradoxical like an oscillating simulacra unable to actualize itself though can be countlessly talked about via  almost every natural language simulation, yet the 'qualified' G is like an unmoved mover able to self-declare and realize itself in an intended and general recursive Turing complete manner...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, how fascinating! 

Comment: @KristianBerry, very unlike you. Anyhow, any wild guesses *quid happened*?

Comment: @KristianBerry, at a loss as to *quare* you brought up *Fitch's paradox*?

Comment: @AgentSmith I have thought betimes that the incompleteness result is a lower mirror of the unknowability result; in my overall theory of these peculiar self-referential sentences, the unprovable sentence is on one end of the set-theoretic world, the unknown one is at the edge of that world's perpetual self-transformation.

Comment: @KristianBerry, what do you think of Fitch's paradox? *Quid vide*? If possible, please start a thread on it (include both the natural language and symbolic logic arguments, if it's not too much for you). Don't reply to this comment in this thread.

Comment: See [Gödel's original paper (1931)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem): "The analogy of this argument with the [Richard antinomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox) leaps to the eye. It is closely related to the "Liar" too."

Comment: @AgentSmith, I am not entirely sure what you are asking here: (1) whether there is an asymmetry? (2) why there is an asymmetry? (3) how could there be an asymmetry if G is based on L?  -- Could you clarify?

Comment: Truth and proof come apart very quickly, is that surprising? We “know” arithmetic exists apart from formal treatments which can’t capture all of it at once. The Liar sentence is not part of a formal system or background like arithmetic, it’s much more free. Asymmetry in asymmetry out. But maybe I’m missing something….

Comment: “He spun his yarn”? Have a bit of respect.

Comment: @gnasher729, good advice.

Comment: It has been proposed that this kind of representational gap or asymmetry has something to do with self-awareness. Maybe no one can really lie to themselves? Maybe "Know Thyself" is ultimately impossible? The mind boggles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since axioms, when true, are true apart from proof, there must be some discrepancy within theories of proof and between provability and truth. If Tarski had not put the liar paradox to use in a way akin to how the unprovable sentence is used to explain the incompleteness phenomena, we might have left off with the discrepancy, then, "just like that."

Another reason for the asymmetry: imagine that there is a function *V*<sub>κ</sub> that can be used to state the ranks of larger and larger cardinals in *V* ("the" universe of sets). So imagine some *V*<sub>κ</sub> ⊨ ZFC: this κ is a [worldly cardinal](https://jdh.hamkins.org/tag/worldly-cardinals/). But the given function can be relativized to any theory: for example, *V*<sub>ℵ<sub>ω</sub></sub> ⊨ ZFC<sup>minus replacement</sup>, so ℵ<sub>ω</sub> is worldly for ZFC *sans* replacement. The point being: if a cardinal is large enough to give a model of a theory, then it captures the spirit of the "world" of a whole theory; being able to give a model means establishing consistency; so worldliness is a function of incompleteness, "but we are certainly not done!"

For go to the other end of a well-founded world: to a well-founded set of all *knowable* sets. This set will not be itself knowable, for if it were, it would be an element of itself and hence not well-founded. So there appears to be some sort of possible limit on our well-founded knowledge (of well-founded sets). This "limitative result" seems like an echo of the liar paradox (when it comes to the paradox of the self-unknown sentence) and of incompleteness (when it comes to Fitch's knowability result). Note that the well-founded set of knowable sets must be astronomically larger than the smallest worldly cardinal, per ZFC (if we accept [Reinhardts](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Reinhardt) and [Berkeleys](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Berkeley) as knowable, then the unknowable cardinal is beyond them, etc.).

Think also of, "This sentence is not understood." This might have little, if anything, to do with the sentence being true or false (unlike proof and knowledge, which are factive). Yet so what use can, "This sentence is understood," for example, be put to, if any? (C.f. whether the honest sentence, "This sentence is true," has any use, Tarskian or otherwise. Or then, "This sentence is provable," "This sentence is known," and so on. Our exploration of symmetries and asymmetries, here, will go on for a long time...)

**Corollary:** for some extra-bizarre reasoning about parathetic sentences, see [this PhilosophySE question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90857/the-absorption-of-parathetic-sentences-into-the-one-true-fact).

---

**Another asymmetry:** one way to analyze parathetic sentences is by converting them into questions and checking whether their erotetic counterparts are "malformed." "Is this sentence false?" is malformed, for example, because questions aren't truth-apt. "Is this sentence unprovable?" is *not* malformed, however, because questions are, in fact, unprovable (in the relevant sense of the words "provable," etc.). (One might think that answering, "No," to, "Is this sentence false?" would not be amiss if one did not mean to imply that the question was true instead, as if the question was, "Is this sentence untrue?" in the first place. I admit that I am uncertain about how this qualification affects the issue of an erotetic counterpart to the liar assertion. I think what we might say is that, "Is this sentence false?" has a correct answer, "No," whereas, "Is this sentence unprovable?" has a correct answer, "Yes," which difference is where the key erotetic asymmetry appears.)

Or compare, "Let this sentence be false," to, "Let this sentence be unprovable." The first is misguided, since imperatives aren't truth-apt as such. However, the second is *not* misguided, since imperatives aren't proof-apt as such, either! (Though note, then, that, "Let this sentence be not true," should be fine, since as an imperative it is neither true nor anti-true (false).)

---

**An asymmetry in another dimension:** in the above, I obliquely mentioned the [knower paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-paradoxes/#KnoPar). As it turns out, there are at least two fundamental parathetic such sentences, though:

1. This sentence is known to be not true.
2. This sentence is not known to be true.

The paradox resulting from (1) is apparently more soluble, along one dimension, than that resulting from (2). But now compare:

3. This sentence is not provably true.
4. This sentence is provably not true.<sup>**!!!**</sup>

If (1) and (2) are both paradoxical, but (3) is useful in a way that (4) is not (although perhaps (4) can be put to some other use...), then we see an asymmetry between knowability and provability, too (not surprising, since if axioms are knowable, there are knowable-but-unprovable things from the get-go).

---

<sup>**!!!**</sup>Suppose that (4) is true. Then it can be proven false. But if it is proven false, then it must be provably true instead. But then we seem to have a proof that it is false. Suppose that (4) is false. Then by *A* implies *A*, we seem to have a proof that it's false, but then it is what it says it is, i.e. is true. QED, for better or worse! (But note that it is possible to think that in the case of these sentences, the distinction between truth and falsity has dissolved, and we can even show this to be so, perhaps.)

Comment: Over me paygrade mon ami. *Obscurum per obscuris*? *What does it matter?* Anyhow, it appears that you're trying to set down some *boundary conditions*, which is *standard procedure* in formalized discourse. Are you going to consider my request, in re *Fitch's paradox*?

Comment: @AgentSmith I could try asking a question about the similarities, if any, between incompleteness and unknowability... I think there might be a question of this nature here, I don't clearly recall :/ I will look into the matter...

Comment: Well, what about the disturbing  fact that Gödel did *prove* the Gödel sentence G even though it says it is *unprovable*, in direct contradistinction to the liar sentence L of which both assumptions end nowhere. The Gödel Asymmetry!

Comment: @AgentSmith IIRC the technical content of the sentence Gödel used was not necessarily directly self-referential, and is such as can be justified in an "outside the system" way (I think Douglas Hofstadter presents G as directly self-referential, to be sure.) But yes, G can be true, whereas L seems to be neither true nor false, except there are further problems with saying L is neither true nor false, etc. Personally, I think that for L, the solution is that it is predicate-false but propositional-true, so that we need a more discriminating sense of kinds of truth to see the solution.

Comment: What does it mean for G to be "outside the system"?

Comment: @AgentSmith a theory with a lower "strength" can't prove its own consistency, but it can have its *relative* consistency proven by a "stronger" theory. Whence worldly and inaccessible cardinals are "theoretically stronger" than ZFC, etc.